# Running datafusion query-aws-s3 example results to an error

Tags: amazon-s3, rust, rust-cargo, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-datafusion

I am specifically running this [example](https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion/blob/main/datafusion-examples/examples/query-aws-s3.rs) from datafusion. I get this error

```
Error: ObjectStore(Generic { store: "S3", source: Error { retries: 0, message: "No Body", source: Some(reqwest::Error { kind: Status(403), url: Url { scheme: "https", cannot_be_a_base: false, username: "", password: None, host: Some(Domain("s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")), port: None, path: "/nyc-tlc/csv_backup/yellow_tripdata_2022-02.csv", query: None, fragment: None } }), status: Some(403) } })
```

I populated my AWS access key and secret access key - no mispelling.

Was anyone able to run this specific example from datafusion?

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion
cd arrow-datafusion
# Download test data
git submodule update --init

# Run the `csv_sql` example:
# ... use the equivalent for other examples
cargo run --example query-aws-s3
```

Comment: Please *include* a [mre] within the post. While you can leave the link, it being the sole source of necessary information is *not* enough for several reasons.